# JS check if a script with a given source has been added

Tags: javascript

Using only JS I need a way to see if a script with a given source has been added to the dom before I add something so as to avoid a clash.

ie I want to check to see if any script tags have been added with 'somedomain' in the src. if there is do x, if not do y

```
<script src="http://www.somedomain.com/ascript.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well then loop through the existing `script` elements, and look at their `src` attribute …

Answer (score 1):

```
var tags = document.getElementsByTagName('script');

function hasDomain(tags, somedomain) {
  var found = false;
  var regex = new RegExp(somedomain, 'gi');
  for (var i = 0, l = tags.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (regex.test(tags[i].src) === true) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
  }
  return found;
}

hasDomain(tags, 'www.somedomain.com'); // true
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/DSLtK/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var scripts = document.getElementsByTagName("script");  // get all the script elements

var anyHasDomain = false,  // no one has the domain yet
    domain = "http://www.somedomain.com/ascript.js"; // the domain to look for

for(var i = 0;i < scripts.length; i++){
    if(scripts[i].src === domain)  // if any has domain 
        anyHasDomain = true;    // set true
}

if(anyHasDomain) alert("y");  // do x
else alert("n");   // do y
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/d55BZ/)

Hope that helps!